# Layout manager in Qt

Tags: qt, layout-manager

The following quote is from this link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout

> If there already is a layout manager
>   installed on this widget, QWidget
>   won't let you install another. You
>   must first delete the existing layout
>   manager (returned by layout()) before
>   you can call setLayout() with the new
>   layout.

***Question 1***: What does it mean when you say is "layout manager **is installed on** this widget"?

***Question 2***: This link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html shows that there are various forms of layouts like: Horizontal, Vertical, Form Layouts. Grid layout can alone be used to arrange the widgets in the forms supported by other three layouts. Is there any special use of the other three layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A layout is "installed" in a widget when you set it as the widget's layout with `setLayout`. That's all it means.

As for what layouts to use: use the simplest layout that does the job you want. Use nesting (you can add a layout to another layout) to make more complex designs. A grid is not necessarily the easiest to use - you'll soon find yourself with headaches about widgets needing to span multiple rows/columns, spacing difficulties etc... if use a single grid as your layout.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean to say that if one type of layout is already set on a widget, that widget cannot use a different type of layout at the same time?   P.S. I am not yet familiar with the nesting of layout :eek:

Comment: that is exactly what the text you quoted says: a widget can have one, and only one, toplevel layout at a time. having multiple layouts doesn't make sens: what would you display?

Comment: Yes, I am not a native English speaker :banghead: Thanks though :)